# Build Kubernetes from Source on a Windows machine

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to build Kubernetes from source code on a windows machine?

As per development environment setup mentioned in https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/development.md only supported OSs are Linux and MAC

Running build/run.sh shows below:

```
Unsupported host OS.  Must be Linux or Mac OS X.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is yes. Kubernetes source is in [Go](https://golang.org/) and there is [Go compiler](https://dl.google.com/go/go1.11.2.windows-amd64.msi) for Windows.

Another question would be, is it possible to be built easily? And that would be a 'no'  (as of this writing) since you have already seen by running `build/run.sh`. So it's not supported by K8s officially.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try to see if I can make it work with Go.