# Make error while building kubernetes from source code

Tags: windows, powershell, kubernetes

I am trying to build Kubernetes on windows 10 with the recommended instruction:

```
git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes
cd kubernetes
```

and then when I tried:

```
make quick-release
```

I've got error:

```
Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

The Makefile contains only one line `build/root/Makefile` without any space.
I also took a look at the first line at Makefile in aformentioned directory which is a comment `# Copyright 2016 The Kubernetes Authors.`

1. How I can solve the issue?
2. Is there any alternative for `make` command or other approach to build kubernetes on windows?

Comment: Looks like the Makefile is actually a symbolic link that Windows thinks is a plain text file. You could get around this by explicitly specifying the Makefile, but all the commands in build/root/Makefile are actually Linux commands, so they won't work on Windows. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545007/build-kubernetes-from-source-on-a-windows-machine) building kubernetes from source is not officially supported on Windows.

Comment: @equatorialsnowfall Thanks for prompt response. I will try linux.